# Google Safe Browsing API v4 - Empty response

Tags: httprequest, httpurlconnection, httpresponse, safe-browsing

Despite that I check a malicious URL (http://fileserver03.com), empty response returns from **`Google Safe Browsing API v4`**.

**Here is the code I have tried:**

```
String postURL = https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=API_KEY

String requestBody = "{" +
        "    \"client\": {" +
        "      \"clientId\":      \"twittersentidetector\"," +
        "      \"clientVersion\": \"1.0\"" +
        "    }," +
        "    \"threatInfo\": {" +
        "      \"threatTypes\":      [\"MALWARE\", \"SOCIAL_ENGINEERING\"]," +
        "      \"platformTypes\":    [\"ANY_PLATFORM\"]," +
        "      \"threatEntryTypes\": [\"URL\"]," +
        "      \"threatEntries\": [" +
        "        {\"url\": \"http://fileserver03.com\"}," +
        "        {\"url\": \"https://bing.com\"}," +
        "        {\"url\": \"https://yahoo.com\"}" +
        "      ]" +
        "    }" +
        "  }";

URL url = new URL(postURL);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(requestBody);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);
System.out.println("Response Message: " + con.getResponseMessage());

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String output;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((output = in .readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(output);
} in .close();

System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());
```

**Here is the output:**

```
Response Code: 200
Response Message: OK
Response: {}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Safe Browsing API **v4** returns empty JSON with http code 200 if **URLs were not listed** as "MALWARE" or any other "threatTypes" you searched for.

So you can try other URLs to see how response for **Listed** URLs look like.
Try these:

```
http://goooogleadsence.biz/
http://activefile.ucoz.com/
```

Comment: Safe Browsing API v4 returns empty JSON with http_code 200 if URLs were not listed as any threatTypes

Comment: There is something strange. I've added http://activefile.ucoz.com/, but the response is the same: +200 with {}. 
Wow, after some investigation I've find a nice site to test: https://testsafebrowsing.appspot.com/s/phishing.html from 
https://testsafebrowsing.appspot.com

Comment: returns `{}` for the urls you've listed for me as well