# Google "Safe Browsing Lookup API" returns empty array

Tags: php, curl, google-api, safe-browsing-api

I'm trying validate url for comment form.

Then I thought ”[Safe Browsing Lookup API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api)” looked good.

However, the following code only returns an empty array in `$result`.

What can I do to improve this code?

code:

```
<?php
$api_key = 'xxx';
$url = 'https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=' . $api_key;
$data = [
    "client"=>[
      "clientId"      => "yourcompanyname",
      "clientVersion" => "1.5.2"
    ],
    "threatInfo"=>[
      "threatTypes"     =>["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
      "platformTypes"   =>["WINDOWS"],
      "threatEntryTypes"=>["URL"],
      "threatEntries"   =>[
        ["url"=>"http://goooogleadsence.biz/"],
        ["url"=>"http://www.urltocheck2.org/"],
        ["url"=>"http://activefile.ucoz.com/"]
      ]
    ]
];
$data_json = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result); // -> string(3) "{}"
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Maybe simply none of your URLs are on any of the lists to begin with? Quote documentation you linked to - _“If there are no matches (that is, if none of the URLs specified in the request are found on any of the lists specified in a request), the HTTP POST response simply returns an empty object in the response body.”_

Comment: @CBroe I think those URLs are specified.There was listed here→https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249657/google-safe-browsing-api-v4-empty-response

Comment: The JSON data you are creating has the slashes in the URL values escaped, whereas the examples from the documentation don’t - not sure if that makes a difference. Try and encode your data with the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` flag set, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I see.
「$data_json = json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);」
Unfortunately, nothing's changed much since last time.